# Determine program responsible for periodic short-lived network connections

Tags: linux, networking, process, tcpdump, forensics

I am interested in learning the proper procedure to determine which Linux program / process is responsible for a given short-lived network connection which repeats periodically.

Without making any assumptions like "the traffic is on this port and therefore must be related to X program".

I also want to have some verifiable, demonstrable way to be certain this traffic is related to the identified program or process.

Assume, for instance, I am watching `tcpdump` on a Ubuntu distribution and I see:

```
07:28:59.935102 IP 10.8.8.5.57667 > time-a-b.nist.gov.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 48
07:29:00.048145 IP time-a-b.nist.gov.ntp > 10.8.8.5.57667: NTPv3, Server, length 48
08:03:08.184704 IP 10.8.8.5.59451 > time-a-b.nist.gov.ntp: NTPv4, Client, length 48
08:03:08.297119 IP time-a-b.nist.gov.ntp > 10.8.8.5.59451: NTPv3, Server, length 48
```

How can I gather information and determine which program is actually creating it?

NTP call to a time server is only a working example. I wish a solution to apply to other network calls as well. It seems like more and more applications are feeling free to send outbound information and I would like to know which process it is so I can determine its legitimacy.

Answer (score 1):

One possible option is to use the open-source tool [`sysdig`](https://github.com/draios/sysdig/), which will let you trace system calls on a per-process basis.  With `sysdig`, you can monitor for outgoing connections.

Given your example, if you want to know what process is connecting to a remote NTP server, you could use:

```
$ sudo sysdig evt.type=connect and fd.sport=ntp
```

That will filter out `connect()` system calls that have specified the standard NTP port as the server-side port.

To demonstrate, I'll trigger an NTP update:

```
$ sudo ntpdate pool.ntp.org
```

With that, `sysdig` produces the following output:

```
50365 18:54:32.790143415 7 ntpdate (4089388) < connect res=0 tuple=192.168.1.135:33982->173.72.22.244:123
50368 18:54:32.790144930 7 ntpdate (4089388) > connect fd=3(<4u>192.168.1.135:33982->173.72.22.244:123)
50371 18:54:32.790147190 7 ntpdate (4089388) < connect res=0 tuple=192.168.1.135:46730->204.11.201.12:123
50374 18:54:32.790148380 7 ntpdate (4089388) > connect fd=3(<4u>192.168.1.135:46730->204.11.201.12:123)
50377 18:54:32.790150548 7 ntpdate (4089388) < connect res=0 tuple=192.168.1.135:40705->129.250.35.251:123
50380 18:54:32.790151746 7 ntpdate (4089388) > connect fd=3(<4u>192.168.1.135:40705->129.250.35.251:123)
50383 18:54:32.790153641 7 ntpdate (4089388) < connect res=0 tuple=192.168.1.135:42732->104.236.116.147:123
50392 18:54:32.790161130 7 ntpdate (4089388) < connect res=0 tuple=192.168.1.135:36404->173.72.22.244:123
50398 18:54:32.790165853 7 ntpdate (4089388) < connect res=0 tuple=192.168.1.135:50312->204.11.201.12:123
50404 18:54:32.790170315 7 ntpdate (4089388) < connect res=0 tuple=192.168.1.135:37229->129.250.35.251:123
50410 18:54:32.790174565 7 ntpdate (4089388) < connect res=0 tuple=192.168.1.135:59468->104.236.116.147:123
50450 18:54:32.790255847 7 ntpdate (4089388) < connect res=0 tuple=::1:44859->:::123
50453 18:54:32.790257385 7 ntpdate (4089388) > connect fd=3(<6u>::1:44859->:::123)
50456 18:54:32.790260502 7 ntpdate (4089388) < connect res=0 tuple=127.0.0.1:41670->0.0.0.0:123
```

From that output, I know that it was the `ntpdate` program that was connecting to the NTP servers, and that that process' ID was 4089388.

While the above example was NTP specific, `sysdig` will enable you to do similar things for a variety of use cases.  You can see the [sysdig user guide](https://github.com/draios/sysdig/wiki/Sysdig-User-Guide) for more information about the various filter options and output formatting.

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10 `sysdig` version 0.24.1 hung my VM so I updated using install-sysdig to version 0.26.4. Even though `tcpdump` shows ntp traffic for the `timesyncd` connection to NIST, `sysdig` does not report it even when dropping the '''and fd.sport=ntp''' portion of the command.  When I restart the `timesyncd` service using systemctl restart, I do not see the traffic related to the port 135. Where would be the best place to ask usage based questions?

Comment: I am seeing this.  ```93742482 15:10:23.957744845 1 systemd-timesyn (69632) > connect fd=14(<4>) 
93742485 15:10:23.957755156 1 systemd-timesyn (69632) < connect res=0 tuple=NULL 
93742547 15:10:23.958105249 1 tcpdump (69545) > connect fd=4(<u>) 
93742549 15:10:23.958113369 1 tcpdump (69545) < connect res=-2(ENOENT) tuple=NULL```

Comment: Looks like you got it? There was a process with PID 69632, given the truncated name, that's probably `/lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd`

Comment: I had to drop the sport filter so I am not seeing the relationship of the network traffic to the process.

Comment: Why are you looking for traffic on port 135?  NTP is 123.

Comment: Without the port filter, you'll get every `connect()` system call from every process.  Maybe `systemd-timesyncd` isn't using `connect()`.  You might try using only the `sport` filter.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. tcpdump is showing the NTP traffic. Unlike your testcase using ntpdate which can be shown using sport, timesync does not show up using that filter while also using the connect option.

Comment: Try `sudo sysdig fd.sport=123`

Comment: No output from that command while seeing the traffic in tcpdump.

Comment: In that case I'm out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: As a follow up, tests on a fresh ec2 ubuntu instance confirmed ```sudo sysdig fd.sport=123``` is not reporting ```timesyncd``` traffic. 
Also confirmed ```telnet``` open which uses connect() is not detected  when ```fd.sport=``` is used.
It would be ideal if sysdig could be configured to monitor all traffic for a given network interface, but I am not aware of any such option.
   
At this point, its not clear to me how sysdig could be used to correlate and investigate specific reoccuring traffic seen in tcpdump and relate it to a specific process or application.

Comment: Like I said, I'm out of ideas.  I demonstrated it works for me with `ntpdate`; I can't explain why it doesn't work for you.  `sysdig` is a system call monitor, so it isn't aware of the network interfaces.